# Android Retrofit post method

Tags: android, retrofit

I have this post method, this dont have body but i need recieve this data in a Object

```
public interface ElementApi {
    @POST()
    Call<List<Element>> getElement();

}
```

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "Title": "Cuenta corriente de ahorro",
            "Description": "Encuentra una cuenta corriente para tu empresa ahora en BNB",
            "LongDescription": null
        },
    ]
}
```

The console response is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.johnnhidalgo/com.example.joh.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://test/api/Values
```

How can i resolve that?

Comment: where is your url?

Comment: I have RetroInstance class in this  i call

Comment: public static String BASE_URL = "http://mobiletestws/api/Values";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    public static Retrofit getRetroClient() {

        if(retrofit == null ) {

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

Comment: miss a `"/"` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all. Your base url should end with a /

```
BASE_URL = "mobiletestws/api/Values/";
```

like so. While we are at it, your baseUrl doesn't look like a url. It should be with a domain like this http://example.com/api/